# displaying date and time restricted results

Tags: php, mysql, date, filter

I have a list which shows all the orders that have been placed with the company, from the beginning. the php script for this is shown below:

```
<?php
    if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'])) {
      $cID = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_GET_VARS['cID']);
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.customers_id, o.payment_method, o.date_purchased, o.franchise_id, o.last_modified, o.date_allocated, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.customers_id = '" . (int)$cID . "' and o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by orders_id DESC where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')";
    } elseif (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']) && is_numeric($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['status'] > 0)) {
      $status = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']);
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.franchise_id,o.date_purchased, o.last_modified, o.currency, o.currency_value, o.date_allocated, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and s.orders_status_id = '" . (int)$status . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by o.orders_id DESC where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00') ";
    } else {
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.date_purchased, o.franchise_id, o.last_modified, o.date_allocated, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by o.orders_id DESC where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')";
    }
    $orders_split = new splitPageResults($HTTP_GET_VARS['page'], MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS, $orders_query_raw, $orders_query_numrows);
    $orders_query = tep_db_query($orders_query_raw);
    while ($orders = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query)) {
    if ((!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID']) || (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID'] == $orders['orders_id']))) && !isset($oInfo)) {
        $oInfo = new objectInfo($orders);
      }

      if (isset($oInfo) && is_object($oInfo) && ($orders['orders_id'] == $oInfo->orders_id)) {
        echo '              <tr id="defaultSelected" class="dataTableRowSelected" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID', 'action')) . 'oID=' . $oInfo->orders_id . '&action=edit') . '\'">' . "\n";
      } else {
        echo '              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id']) . '\'">' . "\n";
      }
?>
                <td class="dataTableContent"><?php echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID', 'action')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id'] . '&action=edit') . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_ICONS . 'preview.gif', ICON_PREVIEW) . '</a>&nbsp;' . $orders['customers_name']; ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php echo strip_tags($orders['order_total']); ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="center"><?php echo tep_datetime_short($orders['date_purchased']); ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php echo $orders['orders_status_name'].' '.'['.$orders ['franchise_id'].']'; ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php if (isset($oInfo) && is_object($oInfo) && ($orders['orders_id'] == $oInfo->orders_id)) { echo tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icon_arrow_right.gif', ''); } else { echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icon_info.gif', IMAGE_ICON_INFO) . '</a>'; } ?>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I've tried using `where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')` to display only orders placed after 17:00:00 the previous day to 17:00:00 on the current day. The code above displays an error. Any help on fixing?

Comment: 1990 called, he wants his code back...

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: ...date_purchased BETWEEN '".$date1." 17:00:00' AND '".$date2." 17:00:00'...

Comment: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')' at line 1`

Comment: And what's the full query that you tried? (And @Dave may be on to something)

Comment: I would help, but you used my answer and didn't mark it correct.  Now you're asking another question about it.

Comment: Waitasec waitasec waitasec...was your entire query "where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')"? If so, that's not a valid SQL query.

Comment: @wes, I looked at your answer, and you didn't provide the SELECT part of the query. Assuming the asker is new to SQL, no wonder he didn't accept it; it didn't work for him.

Comment: Ya, you're right.  Should have spoon fed him. From the looks of it, he knows atleats the very basics.

Comment: @user180857 does the query work now as you would expect, after using my answer from below? if not, let us know the current status.

Comment: @wes, it kept coming up with too many errors, in the end I found a different way to complete it, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is part of your query:

```
where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by o.orders_id DESC where date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00')";
```

The Ordering is incorrect.  `ORDER BY` is always last, in addition you can't have multiple "`WHERE`" statements, where after the first one it becomes AND/OR depending on your logic.

Compare these two side by side, `WHERE` was changed to `AND`, and `ORDER BY` was put at the end.

```
where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' AND date_purchased = CONCAT(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), '17:00:00') order by o.orders_id DESC ";
```

Cheers,

Wes

Answer (score 2):

check for the value of variable `TABLE_ORDERS` and it needs to be `o.date_purchased`

Comment: +1: I think you're on to something; the where clause wasn't using the table as a prefix

Comment: Look at his queries, the order and syntax is actually incorrect.

Comment: `ORDER BY` needs to be after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Well, not only that, he has multiple WHERE's.  As I stated in my answer below